I'm trying to play media files in m4a format, but the file is not visible. ENOENT (No such file or directory)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: io.eduonline.devrush.devrushlmsmultiplatform.androidApp, PID: 21917
java.io.FileNotFoundException: OUR6G_IgJkCvBg5qurB2Ag/audios/FpHO919GeEOCgM52fnuq9g.m4a: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:574)
at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:160)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1235)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1213)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1178)
at app.lexilabs.basic.sound.Audio.load(Audio.android.kt:54)
I use this library https://github.com/LexiLabs-App/basic/blob/main/basic-sound/README.md
val audio = Audio(audioUrl, false)
audioUrl = OUR6G_IgJkCvBg5qurB2Ag/audios/FpHO919GeEOCgM52fnuq9g.m4a
